# phonegap + iOS, http request always return status 0 on local files

Tags: javascript, ios, http, cordova

I am using Phonegap 3.3.0 and on iOS, the following http request always returns 0, whether the file exists or not !!

```
var url = './images/pros/imagefile.png'; 
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
http.open('HEAD', url, false); 
http.send(); 
http.status
```

It returns 0 if the file exists, but if I try a fake wrong url :

```
var url = 'httpbabla/images/pros/imagefile.pngfkjdqmkfjdmqsl';
```

or

```
var url = 'www/images/pros/imagefidddddddle.pngooijijijiojs';
```

it still returns 0.

Is it a phonegap bug ? If not, then how to quickly distinguish existing local files from unexisting files with Phonegap and iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
    function UrlExists(url)
{
    if ( isPhoneGap && isIOS() ) {
        if (url.fileExists()){ //see prototype below
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open("HEAD", url, false);
            http.send();
        }
        catch (err) {
            //alert("An error:" + err.name + "---" + err.message);
        }
        //return http.status!=404;
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("http.status="+http.status);
            return http.status==200 || http.status==0;
        }
    }
}
// check local file existance for iOS
String.prototype.fileExists = function() {
    filename = this.trim();
    var response = jQuery.ajax({
        url: filename,
        type: 'HEAD',
        async: false
    }).status;  
    return (response != "200") ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with an asynchronous request and `onload` and `onerror` handlers. Note the use of a `true` parameter as the last argument to `http.open`:

```
var url = 'file:///does/not/exist.jpg'; 
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
http.open('HEAD', url, true); 
http.onload = function(e){/* Success! File exists; process the response... */};
http.onerror = function(e){/* Failed - file does not exist - do whatever needs to be done... */};
http.send();
```

Once you call `http.send` your function will be done and control will return to the caller. Whatever processing you need to do on either success or failure will need to be taken care of in the `onload` and `onerror` callbacks. Take the time to learn how to use Javascript callbacks (and closures) if you're not familiar with them - they're one of the most powerful features in the language.

Comment: Hi @sherb, thanks, can you help me make it as a function so I can return false if there is an error : `function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, true);
    http.onerror = function(e){console.log('onerror: ' + JSON.stringify(e));};
    http.send();
    //return http.status!=404;
    if (!isIOS()) {
  return http.status==200;
 } else {
  return (http.status==200 || http.status==0);
 }
}`

Comment: @Louis, I updated my answer. Note that `onerror` and `onload` aren't something you call - they are callbacks called from code within XMLHttpRequest. Put your code inside those functions.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem, the response is the same wether the local url exists or not. Do you have another idea ? Why this weird behavior on Phonegap ?

Comment: @Louis I've tested my answer with the iOS Simulator and Safari. I can't think of anything else to suggest without knowing more about your project.

Comment: thanks a lot, indeed I don't know what's happening with this. I found a workaround, I am posting it now.